# Adding Bootstrap content folders to ASP.NET Web Application projects

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, web-applications, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for website design. But I'm not sure how to add files to project. So in Visual Studio 2015 if I create project this way: `File/New/Web Site...` I just can Copy/Paste `css, fonts, js` folders to the project to open it and make it available in project. But if I add it to `Solution/New Project/ASP.NET Web Application/Empty` or `Web Forms` I can't add Bootstrap folders same way, I can't open this folders  for example as any other `scripts` or `Styles` folders inside the project.

So I'm trying to find some useful guide how to add and use it in my Solution exist web projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this: 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/making-beautiful-style-together-visual-studio-and-bootstrap.html

He uses "NuGet Package Manager", what makes bootstrap easier to implement.